# Fill Action bar SHerlock with items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am implementing ActionBarSherlock. I have disabled icon and title. But still my items are not taking that space.
I have used

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Icon and title are disappeared. But that space is not filled up with my items. I have 5 items like

```
 <item android:id="@+id/Clear"
    android:title="Clear"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/load"
    android:title="Load"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/Undo"
    android:title="Undo"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/save"
    android:title="Save"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
```

But only 3 of them are being shown. and action bar is not full. It's like

[image]

I want all the items to appear in the action bar. what should I do?

EDIT:

I am considering adding tabs to the bar. It gives Run time error. Here is my code for adding tabs (It should be pretty simple but I don't know what am i doing wrong here)

```
Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

        tab.setText("Tab " + i);

        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
    }
```

I think this code should be enough to add tabs to the bar. isn't it?

Comment: question is, do you really need an action bar if it is only buttons? What about just placing a bar with  buttons on it?

Comment: I have this actionBar in my Canvas. It's a finger painting app. I cannot put buttons on canvas. I think ABS is appropriate choice for my Canvas.

Comment: what do you get when you use android:showAsAction="always" on all of them?

Comment: Wow.... I didn't even think It will be helpful to make actions "always" for all the items. But surprisingly, It worked... Thanks a lot! but now, I am also considering adding tabs, that will make the tab navigation easier. Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: android:showAsAction="always" worked for me!. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onPrepareOptionsMen, if you use tabs or viewpager it can allow you to change the buttons according to the tab you are in (just had a switch case):

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.clear();
    switch ((int) _viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        case 0:
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.empty_menu, menu);
            break;
        case 1:
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
            break;
        case 2:
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.empty_menu, menu);
            break;
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Or judte one simple menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

You only need to put your items in a menu xml file

**To add tabs : **

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private static final String     TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ViewPager               _viewPager;
private ActionBar               _actionBar;
private Tab                     _Tab;
private TabsAdapter             _tabAdapter;
private int                     _viewPagerOffScreenLimit        = 10;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        _viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(_viewPagerOffScreenLimit);
        _tabAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, _viewPager);
        _actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        _actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        _actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        _actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        _tabAdapter.addTab(_actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(getTabIndicator(getString(R.string.tab), R.drawable.ic_launcher)), FragmentTab.class, null);
}
private View getTabIndicator(String text, int drawable) {

        View indicator = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, null);
        ((TextView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_title)).setText(text);
        ((ImageView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource(drawable);
        return indicator;
    }

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context               mContext;
        private final ActionBar             mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager             mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo>    mTabs   = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?>  clss;
            private final Bundle    args;
            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }


        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            ((SherlockFragmentActivity) mContext).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really a good approach. I am considering it. But I am having another problem. Tabs are not being added. I am pretty new to These topics. please see my code

        'ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
}'

I get run time error. as usual, Unfortunately, App has stopped.

Comment: if you want to show some code please edit your question :/ here it is hard to read

Comment: done editing. and I am already using that. Its first line of my question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I have added tabs using simple code (which I have written in question) It was just a library fault.

Comment: No prob at least it helped

Comment: Just wondering, When is the method "onPrepareOptionsMenu()" is called. When inflating a menu, i know that every time "menu" button is pressed, this method is called. but in case of action bar, when is it called?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659354/when-and-how-often-onprepareoptionsmenu-method-is-called-for-actionbar